# Красиво и эффективно проанализировать массив

Tags: java

Моя задача в принципе решена, но мне не нравится каким способом.
Есть массив длины > 0 (пусть там будут разные числа `int` для простоты, не сортированы). Метод должен вернуть `true`, если в массиве присутствуют только 2 группы чисел и размеры этих групп равны либо отличаются на 1. Примеры, возвращающие true: `[3,3,5,5]` - 2 группы: 3 и 5 - все по 2шт; или `[8,8,8,8,2,2,2]` - 2 группы: 8-4шт и 2-3шт.
Пример для false: [1,2,3,1,3] - больше чем 2 группы чисел

Без стримов! Остальное можно - стандартные средства джавы.

Пока решение мое такое:

```
public boolean satisfiedBy(int[] mainCards) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> rankFrequencies = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int rank : mainCards) {
        Integer count = rankFrequencies.get(rank);
        if (count == null)
            count = 0;
        rankFrequencies.put(rank, count + 1);

        // check if there is no more than 2 groups
        if (rankFrequencies.size() > 2)
            return false;
    }

    if (rankFrequencies.size() != 2)
        return false;

    // check if two groups's sizes differs no more than by 1
    Object[] entries = rankFrequencies.entrySet().toArray();
    if (Math.abs(((Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>) entries[0]).getValue() - ((Entry<Integer, Integer>) entries[1]).getValue()) > 1)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Не нравится `Object[] entries = rankFrequencies.entrySet().toArray();`
и его приведение к нужному типу:

```
if (Math.abs(((Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>) entries[0]).getValue() - ((Entry<Integer, Integer>) entries[1]).getValue()) > 1)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант - хороший вариант. Только непонятно, зачем `Object`. Возьмите `keyset` как массив целых и вычитайте 0 из 1

Comment: Во-первых, мне нужен valueSet. А во-вторых в любом случае toArray() возвращает массив Object-ов. Поэтому в любом случае нужно приведение типов

Comment: `.toArray(new Integer[myset.size()])`. Ну и зачем вам `valueSet`, когда возвращаете логическое значение?

Comment: Да, на перегруженный метод я не посмотрел. Мне нужно сравнивать не ключи, а значения, т.е. количества ключей

Comment: Вам нужно сравнивать не ключи и не значения, а количество одинаковых элементов. Реализовать же это можно множеством экзотических способов. Подобные задачки - хорошая разминка для ума. Diraria предложил(а) хорошие варианты, абсолютно справедливо  выбрали его(ее) ответ, но что касается использования в реальном коде - ваш подход (не реализация!!!) более правилен.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется, что наиболее производительный способ выглядит так:

- обозначим за `array[0]` первый элемент массива
- находим любой элемент `x`, не равный `array[0]`
- проверяем, что каждый элемент массива равен либо `x`, либо `array[0]`
- считаем число вхождений элементов `x` и `array[0]`
- проверяем, что они различаются не более чем на один

Вариант с одним проходом по массиву ([проверка на Ideone](https://ideone.com/3FJWR3)):

```
public static boolean satisfiedBy(int[] array) {
    Integer anotherValue = null;
    int numberOccurrencesOfFirstElement = 0;
    for (int value : array) {
        if (value == array[0]) {
            ++numberOccurrencesOfFirstElement;
        } else if (anotherValue != null && anotherValue != value) {
            return false;
        } else {
            anotherValue = value;
        }
    }
    return anotherValue != null && Math.abs(array.length - numberOccurrencesOfFirstElement * 2) <= 1;
}
```

Чуть более читаемый вариант с двумя проходами по массиву ([проверка на Ideone](https://ideone.com/xHU29D)):

```
public static boolean satisfiedBy(int[] array) {
    int element0 = array[0];
    Integer element1 = null;

    for (int value : array)
        if (value != element0)
            element1 = value;
    if (element1 == null)
        return false;

    int count0 = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    for (int value : array) {
        count0 += value == element0 ? 1 : 0;
        count1 += value == element1 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return count0 + count1 == array.length && Math.abs(count0 - count1) <= 1;
}
```

Comment: В массиве могут быть и другие числа.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, вроде оба варианта корректно обрабатывают эту ситуацию: в первом есть проверка `if (anotherValue != null && anotherValue != value) { return false; }`, во втором `count0 + count1 == array.length`

Comment: Пожалуй, вы правы. Второй вариант может быть не очень эффективным, если  массив длинный. А вот первый мне понравился. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Давно с джавой не работал, потому эдакий java-псевдокод

```
Map<Int, Int> out = new HashMap<>();

for (int value : array) {
    out.put(value, out.get(value) == null ? 1 : out.get(value) + 1);
    if( out.size() > 2 ) return false;
}

return Math.abs((out.get(out.keySet.toArray[0]) - out.get(out.keySet.toArray[1]))) < 2;
```

UPD Сначала написал ответ, а потом внимательно вопрос прочитал. :) Как видите, решение практически полностью совпадает, за исключением некоторых нюансов. Решил не удалять, потому как вдруг чем-то да поможет код улучшить

Comment: чтобы компилировалось можно [вот так](https://ideone.com/cba3d4) изменить)

Comment: и ещё кстати вместо `out.get(out.keySet.toArray[0])` можно сделать `out.values.toArray[0]`

Comment: @diraria ну да, как-то так. Я уж с год как на kotlin перешел - там оно все гораздо лаконичней получается :)

Comment: Я бы всё-таки по памяти соптимизировал. Если массив из 2млрд последовательных чисел, зачем нам вычислять частоту каждого из них? Уже на 3 шаге можно вернуть результат.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду? Если на третьей итерации появится третье значение, то отработает  `if( out.size() > 2 ) return false;`

Comment: Это был коммент для кода diraria

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець чтобы ответить конкретному человеку, используйте символ `@` и ник в начале комментария. Например коммент конкретно для вас должен начинаться с `@ОлексійМоренець` ;)

Comment: @rjhdby прикольно, а где автоподстановка как в фейсбуке? ))) у вас же непечатаемое имя.